# How to gain access to r_1st_connections of LinkedIn API v2

Tags: linkedin-api

With the new v2 of LinkedIn API, how do we apply for r_1st_connections scope to be added to our apps? Or any scopes other than the barest minimum?

(Background: There have been some other attempts to get LinkedIn to respond to this, but so far no luck. Having attempted through their website to find the correct person to contact, I have been consistently diverted here, being told to tag my requests with #LinkedIn and they will be read by the appropriate persons! The API promises a lot, but delivers way short of anything that would appear useful to a developer.)

Comment: LinkedIn support has been notoriously absent from SO despite assurances they would be monitoring for questions.